# Merge references to duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

This feels very simple and complex at the same time, but I can't quite get my head around an appropriate way of going about this as mysql query.

I have a table of tags called **categories** that should only have unique titles for the field *cat_title*. However, I've noticed that there are multiple rows with the same *cat_title* field name.

I want to delete all but the first instance of any duplicates. Simple enough, yes. But another table, **tagging** has a field called *tagging_cat_id* that references the identifier field, *cat_id* in the **categories** table. Deleting duplicates will break these references and point to nothing.

So, the more complex aspect is finding any *tagging_cat_id* field that references a duplicate row that's about to be deleted and change it to reference the (soon to be unique, single) first row of this *cat_title*

I am a novice at mysql and this is a bit out of my depth. I was almost tempted to do this manually by hand in a gui. Is there a simple enough method of doing this as a query that I could run on occasion to perform the above? (until what's causing duplicates to be created is resolved). Distrib version is 5.7.21.

## Sample Data

**Categories**

```
+--------+-----------+
| cat_id | cat_title |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | green     |
|      2 | red       |
|      3 | blue      |
|      4 | green     |
|      5 | green     |
|      6 | red       |
|      7 | white     |
+--------+-----------+
```

**Tagging**

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
| tagging_id | tagging_record_id | tagging_cat_id |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
|          1 |                 1 |              1 |
|          2 |                 1 |              2 |
|          3 |                 2 |              7 |
|          4 |                 3 |              5 |
|          5 |                 4 |              6 |
|          6 |                 5 |              4 |
|          7 |                 5 |              3 |
|          8 |                 6 |              5 |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

### I want to convert the above to the following:

**Categories**

```
+--------+-----------+
| cat_id | cat_title |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | green     |
|      2 | red       |
|      3 | blue      |
|      7 | white     |
+--------+-----------+
```

**Tagging**

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
| tagging_id | tagging_record_id | tagging_cat_id |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
|          1 |                 1 |              1 |
|          2 |                 1 |              2 |
|          3 |                 2 |              7 |
|          4 |                 3 |              1 |
|          5 |                 4 |              2 |
|          6 |                 5 |              1 |
|          7 |                 5 |              3 |
|          8 |                 6 |              1 |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: The issue and solution are obvious, the question is "what do you need now ?" a faster algorithm ? more secure way? an automated tool ?

Comment: what you are looking ??  is not clear  ..  if  you have a proper data model  is possible  delete and update with two queries..  so you should add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: @scaisEdge In what format would the data sample be best expressed? Showing some sample rows in both tables, that are relevant to the question? Apologies, this is really not my area, I'm fine with showing javascript examples but amn't sure of the clearest way to demonstrate relevant table or db information here.

Comment: if you shoud the data sample and the expected result as tabular text is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use this query:

```
SELECT cat_id, MIN(cat_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cat_title) min_id
FROM categories
```

to identify for each `cat_id` the minimum `cat_id` with the same `cat_title` so you can update the table:

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT cat_id, MIN(cat_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cat_title) min_id
  FROM categories
)
UPDATE tagging t
INNER JOIN ids i ON i.cat_id = t.tagging_cat_id
SET t.tagging_cat_id = i.min_id
```

Then you can delete the duplicates:

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT cat_id, MIN(cat_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cat_title) min_id
  FROM categories
)
DELETE c 
FROM categories c INNER JOIN ids i 
ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id AND i.min_id < c.cat_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99e9021a64db0bce97821c137155f500).

For previous versions of MySql that do not support window functions and CTEs:

```
UPDATE tagging t
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.cat_id = t.tagging_cat_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT cat_title, MIN(cat_id) min_id
  FROM categories 
  GROUP BY cat_title
) m ON m.cat_title = c.cat_title
SET t.tagging_cat_id = m.min_id
```

and:

```
DELETE c1 
FROM categories c1 INNER JOIN categories c2 
ON c2.cat_title = c1.cat_title
WHERE c1.cat_id > c2.cat_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=31212aa1b953e64a65a0fc6ef76768c2).

Results:

| cat_id | cat_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | green |
| 2 | red |
| 3 | blue |
| 7 | white |

and:

| tagging_id | tagging_record_id | tagging_cat_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 | 3 |
| 8 | 6 | 1 |

Comment: Apologies, it's: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21

Comment: @biscuitstack I have added code for version 5.7

Comment: Beautiful, this worked as hoped. Thanks for the short comments too, I'm going to work my way through this to better understand the techniques. Much appreciated.